# Changing value and triggering input in IE

Tags: jquery

I need to forcefully display TypeAhead results once they're loaded.
In the documentation, it states I need to change the value of the `input`, then change it back to the original (All while triggering the `input`) to make it work.

I'm using the following code:

```
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var val = $(element).val();
        $(element).focus();
        $(element).eq(0).val("").trigger("input");
        $(element).eq(0).val(val).trigger("input");
    }, 500);
```

This works in Chrome, however, and not IE.

Comment: Any errors thrown in the console?

Comment: you mean $(element).eq(0).val("").trigger("change"); ??

Comment: @PatsyIssa No errors at all.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi `"change"` doesn't work.

Comment: try use trigger("keypress")

Comment: @AnisHikmatAbu-hmiad `trigger("keypress")` also not working.

Comment: Can you add a link or a jsfiddle please?

Comment: aha, what about if we change a eq(0) to css nth-child(0) ?!

Comment: @OfirBaruch No, not without having to setup twitter's typeahead just to take pot-shots at getting this right.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this myself with some hacky code:

```
    var val = $(element).val();

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(element).focus();
    }, 50);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(element).eq(0).val("").trigger("keypress");

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).eq(0).val(val).trigger("keypress");
        }, 80);

    }, 75);
```

Looks like I need more time between the events... If anyone can see a better way of doing this, I'm open to any ideas.

**Edit:** For those interested, this does *NOT* work in Chrome.
**Edit 2:** This is useless if you're looking for any type of speed or functionality. It breaks away from the clean running of TypeAhead...

Comment: Can't you use the handler instead of using setTimeout 3 times?
Something like: `$(element).focus(function(){ $(this).eq(0)... });` ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I've tried to put this in the `focus` event - It simply refuses to work.